# Full-screen UIView subclass as veil not consuming touch events

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a tab bar app that works. Each tab is a `UINavigationController` whose root view is some kind of `UIViewController`, often a `UITableViewController`.

There are instances in the app where I want to display a full-screen "veil" with a message about what's happening until some operation completes. The point is to swallow up any touches on the UI that would navigate away from where the operation started.

The veil is a UIView subclass. There is one singleton instance of the class. When displayed, I insert it as a subview of the `UITabBarController` view. The view appears over the entire UI, tab bar included. Great!

Here's the problem. I can tap the tabs and the UI changes. What I would have expected is that my veil view would have just swallowed up the touches.

I have implemented in my veil class the various touches{Began|Ended|Moved|Canceled} methods (as do-nothing methods), but the touches are still picked up by the tab bar, and frankly by any object under whereever I happen to touch.

I've also tried overriding a number of other methods including nextResponder, hitTest:withEvent:, etc, to no avail.

I am a little stumped at this point. I'm hoping someone will have some sage advise. :-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not safe to modify the view hierarchy of framework classes. You would be much better-served simply adding it as a subview of the window itself. As for consuming touches, if making this change doesn't work, then you should also verify that `userInteractionEnabled` is set to YES on the view. You should not have to actually implement any touch-related methods.

Comment: @Kevin-Ballard: Thanks for that. So I achieved the same visual effect I was after by doing as you suggested: inserting the veil as a subview of the delegate's window. And, the veil's `userInteractionEnabled` flag is set to YES. I commented out my null implementations of the touch handling methods. The touches continue to be passed through to the underlying views. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @MarkGranoff: I assume it also fails if you leave the null implementations in place? And you inserted it at the root of the window? The most likely reason I can think of for your behavior is if a superview has a UIGestureRecognizer, but if you're at the root of the window then that's not the case. The only other thing I can think of is your alpha. Did you set the `alpha` property on your view? If `alpha` is `0.05` or less, touches skip the view. It should be set at `1` and your view should simply have no background color.

Comment: @Kevin-Ballard: Yes, with or without the null implementations, same behavior. No UIGestureRecognizers in use, at least not explicitly by me. The alpha property is set, but to 0.65. So I set it to 1, and used clearColor so I could see what might be happening. Still fails. By the way, the view is inserted with code like this `[[myApp delegate].window addSubview:[Veil theVeil]]`. That certainly works (I see the veil), and I can't think of another way to do it "the right way." Truly bizarre.

Comment: @Kevin-Ballard: Oh, I also setExclusiveTouch to YES for the veil view, which I thought would _surely_ do the trick, but it had no effect.

Comment: @MarkGranoff: `setExclusiveTouch` doesn't actually do what you think it does. It has to do with how multiple touch events are handled and has no effect whatsoever on a single touch.

Comment: @Kevin-Ballard: Ah! Interesting. Ok then. :-) I have also tried making the veil view firstResponder and implementing `-(BOOL)canResignFirstResponder` for the Veil class (returning NO) with no change in behavior.

Comment: @MarkGranoff: first responder doesn't affect touch events. Have you tried implementing a non-null touch handler in the veil and seeing if that actually ever gets called?

Comment: @Kevin-Ballard: Well, that's a good point. They do not get called. Doh! Now that is perplexing. But also suggests that my veil is not even part of the responder chain. How is that possible?

Comment: @Kevin-Ballard: So once I implemented hitTest:withEvent:, the other touch methods started to get called. BUT, the touches are still passed through to the covered UI elements (a UITableView and the tab bar). Weird.

Comment: @MarkGranoff: That doesn't make any sense. I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: @Kevin-Ballard: Yeah, and they are not called consistently. Most odd. Thanks for trying! If you wake up in a cold sweat with any other ideas, I'll be interested! :-)

Comment: @MarkGranoff: This is really strange. Trick with window always worked for me. For a quick test try to add opaque UIView with some flashy color in `keyWindow` of your application and observe it's behavior. As a last resort you can set `rootViewController` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and modify window.rootViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled on adding/removing veil.

Comment: @hoha: Thanks for the suggestions. Tried adding the veil to keyWindow with no change in behavior. Also tried setting userInteractionEnabled to NO without a difference. No joy. There is something else that must be going on in my code. :-)

Comment: @MarkGranoff: It must be so, try test this on empty app.

Comment: I added some debugging statements to see when things were actually happening. What I discovered is that the veil is actually coming down at the right time, and pretty soon after going up. The problem is two fold: the table is taking a long time to redraw itself and when the veil comes down the screen is not updated immediately. So it *look* like the veil is up, but in fact it isn't, which explains why the touches "go through" to the underlying view (a table in this case). Fwiw, it's a table w/ a search display controller that the veil is covering.

Comment: A final comment. The crux of my problem is that the veil is getting dropped too soon. In the code, it's after the call to `reloadData`. But apparently, `reloadData` is executed asynchronously. So the veil was actually coming down too soon. What I need is to be able to drop the veil AFTER the display updates. How to do that... a notification or something like that, perhaps....

Comment: And the answer was this: `reloadData` does it's work asynchronously. But two other APIs do not: `insertSections` and `deleteSections`. Using these methods on the tableView inside a `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` block, my veil stays up until after the table actually updates on screen. Yay!

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and came up with a hacky solution. In the `init` of your custom UIView class, create a dummy UIView that's impossible to hit, for example `[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-1, -1, 0, 0)]`. Or actually, I think any UIView not attached to the window works. Then, in `hitTest:withEvent:`, have it return the dummy view for every point not in your area of interest.